# Creaking on hard pedaling

Tags: mountain-bike, creak

I'm trying to locate a creak when I pedal uphill.

Tightened chainring bolts and rear derailer hanger. I don't see much to do with the bottom bracket (sram xx1). Pedals are tight. Chain, cassette, and rear hub are new.

It sounds like it's coming from the bottom bracket but everything sounds like it's coming from there.

What could it be?

2015 Mondraker Foxy carbon

edit: It's not the bottom bracket or the chainring or the wheels. I can reproduce it by pushing the suspension. I have no idea what to do with the linkages though.

Comment: Bottom bracket has bearings that are under heavy load when pedaling. It is one of the most common sources of creaking, and press fit versions are even worse.

Comment: How's your technical skill?  Would you be prepared to attempt removing, greasing and refitting the existing BB?

Comment: Simple thing to try, does the creak go away when you pedal standing up? If so then it's more than likely the seatpost/saddle rails.

Comment: Foxy Carbons are full suspension bikes. Are you sure it's not a linkage? Did you remove the rear triangle recently?

Comment: Haven't messed with the triangle. I've done plenty of bottom brackets but never a press fit one

Comment: In my experience, creaky bottom brackets are caused by busted bearings.

Comment: New bottom bracket. Still creaking. What do you mean by busted bearings? Linkage bearings?

Comment: I once thought my BB is creaking, but it was just the saddle. After tigthtening it, the creaking was gone.

Answer (score 2):

I have a carbon hardtail which I used to ride the Great Divide MTB route last summer. About halfway through I had a similar issue which I couldn't seem to resolve; a creak everytime I put power through the pedal stroke. I took apart and cleaned the cranks, pedals, axle, checked BB bearings for play, etc... No change.

Finally, I took my bike in to a local bike shop when we got to the next town and the owner there straight away asked if I'd checked the rear axle. I hadn't as it didn't seem a likely suspect... It turns out, with the large amount of dust and occasional mud the bike had been subjected to and with no opportunity to give it a good thorough clean, some dirt had accumulated between the rear axle quick release clamp and the frame. When I put power through the pedals, the frame was flexing quite significantly ( exacerbated in part because of all the bikepacking gear strapped to it) and causing the axle to creak as it shifted on each stroke. I gave it a good clean, added a drop of lube, tightened it up and... hey presto, problem solved.

Not guaranteed to be this but it's an easy thing to check (especially compared to pulling out your BB) so worth having a look.

Answer (score 1):

Creaking from the bottom bracket is difficult to isolate. It could be as simple as cleats not being tight, water in the bottom bracket, crank arms need retightening, or the most obvious the bottom bracket itself.  I am not familiar with your bike, but generally under load it is more than likely to be the bottom bracket.as your bike is 5 years old I am leaning to the bottom bracket.

Comment: New bottom bracket today and it's still creaking. Going to try the wheels idea next

Answer (score 1):

I had ,every now and then, the same creaking noise "from BB", then I happened to notice that my front wheels' spokes are loose. I tightened them all by half a turn and the creaking noise seams to have stopped. Check your spokes!

Answer (score -2):

It may be your pedals, try a re-grease.

Comment: We're looking for answers with more detail than this. Why do you suspect the pedals need regreasing? Why would under-lubricated pedals only creak under heavy load?

Comment: Welcome to SE - I know what you mean, but others might not.  Could you expand this by saying exactly what should be greased?  The threads, or the bearings, or the shafts, or something else?   Or do you mean add grease to something else that isn't a pedal?   I know its a bit pedantic, but an 8 word answer is lacking in details so use [edit] to embiggen it.